# How to loop through monthly and yearly data in a large Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, netcdf

I am currently writing a program that reads in a total of 324 NetCDF files containing lat, lon, time, and SST values from Jan 1994 to Dec 2020. My goal is to find the average monthly SST in a specifically defined region of the globe (I am calculating for part of the equatorial Pacific region) for each monthly file, and then to plot as a time series. Of note, the SST data is conveniently(?)  3-dimensional including lat, lon, and time attached to each SST value. I have already read in all of the NetCDF files into the program using xarray:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset(r"my_directory\*.nc", autoclose=True)
```

Then, I defined the specific values in the xarray I wanted that only included the lat and lon points for my specified region:

```
sst = ds['sst'][0:324, 1875:2126, 125:751]
```

Then, I simply converted the xarray into a pandas dataframe. I also made sure the time variable was correctly formatted and made columns for "month" and "year" using the DateTimeIndex and to_datetime actions:

```
months_df = sst.to_dataframe()
df = months_df.reset_index(drop=False)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df["year"]=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).year
df['month']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).month
df
```

I end up with a dataframe that looks like this with a whopping 50908824 rows of data:

```
    time             lat        lon            sst          year  month
1994-01-16 12:00:00 -5.0    -170.000000 29.197001   1994    1
1994-01-16 12:00:00 -5.0    -169.919983 29.193001   1994    1
1994-01-16 12:00:00 -5.0    -169.839966 29.176001   1994    1
1994-01-16 12:00:00 -5.0    -169.760010 29.167999   1994    1
1994-01-16 12:00:00 -5.0    -169.679993 29.153999   1994    1
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-12-16 12:00:00 5.0 -120.320007 25.892000   2020    12
2020-12-16 12:00:00 5.0 -120.239990 25.924999   2020    12
2020-12-16 12:00:00 5.0 -120.160034 25.963001   2020    12
2020-12-16 12:00:00 5.0 -120.080017 25.995001   2020    12
2020-12-16 12:00:00 5.0 -120.000000 26.006001   2020    12
```

Once I created the compiled dataframe, I've gotten stuck on the best way to compute the monthly average SSTs. I know I could iterate over every month, and every year, by typing out each month/year combination, but that would take ALOT of lines of code and be quite silly:

```
jan_1994 = df[(df['year'] == 1994) & (df['month'] == 1)]
jan_1994_sst_avg = jan_1994['sst'].mean()
feb_1994 = df[(df['year'] == 1994) & (df['month'] == 2)]
feb_1994_sst_avg = feb_1994['sst'].mean()
mar_1994 = df[(df['year'] == 1994) & (df['month'] == 3)]
mar_1994_sst_avg = mar_1994['sst'].mean()
 .
 .
 .
```

Any help on the best way to go about doing something like this, where a loop is possible to go through each month/year combination and calculate the average SST of each month/year... would be wonderful. I am still new to Python, especially with regards to loops. This seems like my first big task where a loop is possible and help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df.groupby(["year", "month"])["sst"].mean()`

Comment: Wow thank you! I didn't even think of a groupby, I thought a loop would be needed. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very efficient to do in xarray, before going to pandas. After subsetting your data, just use [`xr.DataArray.resample`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.resample.html), e.g.:

```py
sst.resample(time="M").mean()
```